# Webots Pick and Place while loop

Tags: python, position, sensors

I'm very new to coding with python and was looking for any help explaining how to convert a time-based motion into a motion dependent on position with a while loop. In the tutorial this while loop is given as an example:

```
# Monitor the arm joint position to detect when the motion is completed.
while robot.step(timestep) != -1:
    if abs(armPositionSensors[3].getValue() - (-1.2)) < 0.01:
        # Motion completed.
        break
```

The part I'm most confused about is the meaning of the -1.2 and 0.01 values, any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more context to what those values you are working with mean. This question is impossible to answer otherwise. I assume `armPositionSensors[3].getValue()` is some value measured by a sensor. In that case `< 0.01` is most likely a value specifiying the tolerance for some kind of action is will probably be quite specific to the sensor you are using and what you want to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.